# Androidplot plot a half empty line graph

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I want to plot a line graph, which is not "autocompleted". My problem is, 
I want to add XY Points over a time period. But after adding the first point, android plot draws this point in the middle and draws a line form the beginning of the graph to the point and form there to the end of the graph. 
How it is:

[image]

How it should be:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you should add series with Number array which has null values or you can set baundries of graph to higher values